In how many ways can a rook from the bottom left corner of an 8 × 8 chessboard reach the top right corner in exactly 4 moves?
The full question is: In chess, a rook may move any number of squares only either horizontally or vertically. In how many ways can a rook from the bottom left corner of an 8 × 8 chessboard reach the top right corner in exactly 4 moves? (The rook must not be on the top right corner prior to the 4th move.)
I know that the answer is 532, but I'm extremely confused because I cannot figure out how many different cases there will be

Start with one case and continue until you have found all the cases. You don't need to know how many there are in order to find them all. If you still get stuck, edit the question to show all your work up to the point where you got stuck and try to explain why you cannot continue. Then there will be something for someone to answer.

List all options to move Ra1 to h8, then discard the cases not compliant to the given stipulations. This will help to figure out how many different cases there are. Alternatively mind R moving to the right only (upwards is just the same but mirrored, thus times $2$ in the end), there are only seven options (b1..h1), what reduces the level of complexity seriously to seven tasks "how to find a 3-path way to h8". Same technique again will reduce it to "find a 2-path way to h8" -- but there are as many options as to get to the current square from a1. HTH

The left diagram shows the number of paths from anywhere on the board to the upper right corner that have 2 steps. The right diagram is the number of paths to anywhere on the board from the bottom left corner that have 2 steps. They are the same.
The total 4-step paths from bottom left to upper right is the summed product of the matrices, which is $560$. If you prohibit stopping at the upper right corner as an intermediate point on the path, you remove the $2*14$ term there for $532$.
By summed product of the matrices, for cell $(i,j)$, calling the left and right matrices $L,R$, respectively, I mean $\Sigma_{i,j}L_{i,j} \times R_{i,j}$.


Really nice solution, and the diagrams are great! Could you add an explanation of what exactly you mean by "...the product of the matrices, which is $560$"? (I understand your point about $560$ vs $532$, I'm asking about how you're defining the product there). Also you have a small typo in that line (the corners you mention aren't the same as the ones in the diagrams).

@ChrisLewis thanks for the typo catch, I added a sentence about the product of the matrices. I mean cell-by-cell product, summed.

Bear with me.
Label the squares $(row, column)$ where the starting point is $(1,1)$ and the ending point is $(8,8)$.  Now a rook can get from $(1,1)$ to any square in two moves. And it can get from any square to $(8,8)$ in two moves.
For every square $(a,b) \ne (8,8)$, lets consider first, how many ways are there for the rook to get from $(1,1)$ to $(a,b)$ in two moves, and then how many ways are there to get from $(a,b) \to (8,8)$ in two moves.
Part One:  Ways to get to $(a,b)$.
A: If $a\ne 1,b\ne 1$ there are $2$ ways.  Either $(1,1)\to (a,1)\to (a,b)$ or $(1,1)\to (1,b)\to (a,b)$.
B: If $a=1; b\ne 1$ there are $6$ ways. $(1,1)\to (1,c:c\ne 1;c\ne b)\to (1,b)$.
C: If $a\ne 1;b=1$ there are $6$ ways. This is too similar to B: above to be worth commenting on.
D: If $(a,b)=(1,1)$ there are $14$ ways.  Either $(1,1)\to (1,c\ne 1)\to (1,1)$ or $(1,1)\to (d\ne 1, 1)\to (1,1)$.
Part 2: Ways to get for $(a,b)\to (8,8)$
$\alpha$: $a\ne 8; b\ne 8$.  There are $2$ ways.  Either $(a,b)\to (8,b)\to (8,8)$ or $(a,b) \to (a,8) \to (8,8)$.
$\beta$:  $a=8;b\ne 8$.  There are $6$ ways:  $(8,b)\to (8,c:c\ne b;c\ne 8)\to (8,8)$.
$\gamma$:  $a\ne 8; b=8$.  There are $6$ ways that are just like in $\alpha$.
Part 3:  Combining.
There are $36$ squares where $a\ne 1;a\ne 8;b\ne 1;b\ne 8$.  These are squares of Part 1:A so there are $2$ ways to get to each of these $36$ squares.  These squares are of Part $\alpha$ so there are $2$ ways to get from each of these $36$ squares to $(8,8)$.

So there are $36\times 2\times 2 = 144$ ways to go from $(1,1)$ to
$(8,8)$ by passing through one of these $36$ squares an the second
move. [we have accounted for $36$ of the $64$ squares]

There are $12$ squares where $a$ or $b$ but not both are equal to $1$ but neither $a$ nor $b = 8$.  These $12$ squares are of part 1 A or B so there are $6$ ways to get to them.  They are of Part 2 $\alpha$ so there are $2$ ways to get from them to $(8,8)$

So there are $12\times 6\times 2 = 144$ more ways.  [That accounts
for $36+12=48$ of the $64$ squares]

There is one square $(1,1)$ which is Part 1:D. And also of Part 2: $\alpha$.

So there are $1\times 14\times 2=28$ more ways. [That accounts for
$49$ of the $64$ quares]

There are $2$ squares $(1,8)$ and $(8,1)$.  These are of Part 1: B or C so there are $6$ ways to get there.  And they are of Part 2: $\alpha$ or $\beta$ so there are $6$ wasy to get from there.

So that is $2\times 6\times 6 = 72$ more ways.  [That accounts for $51$ of the $64$ squares].

Finally there are $12$ squares $(a,b)$ where either $a$ or $b$ equals $8$ but neither equal $1$.  These are of Part 1: A and of Part 2: $\beta$ or $\gamma$.

So there are $12\times 2\times 6= 144$ ways to pass through this on the way to $(8,8)$.  These accounts for $63$ of the $64$ squares and $(8,8)$ is the final square which we are not allowed to pass through.

So that is $144 + 144 + 28 + 72+144 = 532$

Alternative approach.
Let $~V_k~$ denote a Vertical move of $~k~$ squares, where $~k \in \Bbb{Z_{\neq 0}}.$ 
Let $~H_k~$ denote a Horizontal move of $~k~$ squares, where $~k \in \Bbb{Z_{\neq 0}}.$
So, the problem is reduced to enumerating the number of ordered quadruples that satisfy the original problem's constraints.  Here, each component of a satisfying quadruple will either have form $~V_k~$ or $~H_k.$

$~\underline{\text{Case 1: There is exactly one vertical move}}$
There are $~4~$ positions possible for the vertical move, so reserve the factor of $~4,~$ and assume, without loss of generality, that the ordered quadruple has form $\displaystyle ~\left( ~V_7, ~H_{x_1}, ~H_{x_2}, ~H_{x_3} ~\right).$
Then, $~(x_1,x_2,x_3),~$ must be some satisfying solution to the (enumeration) problem of :

$~x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 7.~$
$~x_1, ~x_2, ~x_3 \in \Bbb{Z_{\neq 0}}.~$
$~x_1, x_3 \in \{1,2,\cdots,7\}.~$

Of the $~(7 \times 7) = 49~$ ways of satisfying the 3rd bullet point above, you must deduct the $~6~$ ways that $~x_1 + x_3 = 7,~$ since this would cause $~x_2 = 0.~$
Therefore, the enumeration for Case 1 is
$$4 \times 43 = 172.$$

$~\underline{\text{Case 2: There is exactly one horizontal move}}$
By considerations of symmetry, the enumeration here, which must match the enumeration of Case 1, must also be
$$4 \times 43 = 172.$$

$~\underline{\text{Case 3: There are exactly two vertical moves}}$
There are $~\displaystyle \binom{4}{2} = 6~$ ways of ordering the moves, so reserve the factor of $~6,~$ and then assume, without loss of generality, that the ordered quadruple has form $\displaystyle ~\left( ~V_{a_1}, ~V_{a_2}, ~H_{b_1}, ~H_{b_2} ~\right).$
Here,$~a_1~$ must be an element of $~\{1,2,\cdots,6\},~$ and the choice of $~a_1~$ determines $~a_2.~$ Considerations of $~b_1,b_2~$ are similar.  Therefore, the enumeration for  Case 3 is
$$6 \times 6 \times 6 = 216.$$

So, the overall enumeration is
$$~172 + 172 + 216 = 560.$$
This computation agrees with the intermediate computation of $~560~$ mentioned in the middle of the answer of RobinSparrow.  Further, I agree with their subsequent analysis, which converts this intermediate computation to the final computation of $~532.~$
In the syntax of my answer, in order to convert the intermediate computation of $~560~$ into the final computation of $~532,~$ you must deduct each of the elements in the set $~T,~$ where each element in $~T~$ will have one of the following four formats:

$\displaystyle \left( ~V_7, ~H_7, ~V_{-k}, ~V_k ~\right).$
$\displaystyle \left( ~V_7, ~H_7, ~H_{-k}, ~H_k ~\right).$
$\displaystyle \left( ~H_7, ~V_7, ~H_{-k}, ~H_k ~\right).$
$\displaystyle \left( ~H_7, ~V_7, ~V_{-k}, ~V_k ~\right).$

For each such format, you must have $~k \in \{1,2,\cdots,7\},~$ so $~T~$ has exactly $~28~$ elements.
Note that it is impossible, following my analysis, to (instead) have a solution where the upper right hand corner is reached after exactly $~3~$ moves.  This is because my use of the syntax $~V_k~$ and $~H_k~$ specifically prohibits $~k = 0.$
